# PHP with XSL & XML

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have two files student.xml & sytle_student.xsl and one file PHP whaich contain form that search for data in the xml file but the result dosen't appear in the style attached in the xsl file 
i used this function

```
               $xslDoc = new DOMDocument();
               $xslDoc->load("style_student.xsl");
               $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
               $xmlDoc->load("student.xml");
               $proc = new XSLProcessor();
               $proc->importStylesheet($xslDoc);
                    echo $proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc);
```

but it generate 2 errors in this line

```
               $proc = new XSLProcessor();
```

The error : Class 'XSLProcessor' not found in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 51

how can i handle this error to display ya result with the xsl style ??

Comment: Did you mean [XSLTProcessor](http://php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php)? If so, you're just missing a "T".

Comment: it will generate the same error i edidted xslt to xsl because the xsl file is .xsl not .xslt but still thesame problem

Comment: The name of the class has nothing to do with the name of the file. Change your code to use XSLTProcessor and post the exact error you get using that. Also, which version of PHP are you using? (You can find detailed information about your PHP installation by using the function `phpinfo();` in your php file.)

Answer (score 3):

The class is called `XSLTProcessor`, the extension is `ext/xsl`.

Check if the extension ext/xsl is loaded.

```
var_dump(extension_loaded('xsl'));
```

If not install the extension and/or change the php.ini to activate it.